# Download all files in a Sharepoint folder using Python?

Tags: python, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a Sharepoint folder, where every week several files would be dumped. Using python, I would like to download all the files from to a local folder location, do some transformations and upload a single consolidated file back to different location on Sharepoint. But whatever calls I am making,  returns an empty JSON file.

Here is the code I have tried till now:

```
import sharepy
sess = sharepy.connect(site='company.sharepoint.com', username='username', password='password')

site = r'https://company.sharepoint.com/'
path = r'/some-site/Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/'

r = sess.get(site + """_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"""+path+"""')/Files""")
r
r.json()['d']['results']
```

`r` object is a `<Response [200]>`.I want to download all the files in Folder3, but it returns empty. If I goto the Sharepoint website, I can see all the files using the same username used to create `sess` object.

I am getting `path` variable from the bottom of the details pane. I have tried many other options than `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl`, but couldn't seems to be working.

I am new to Python and have no clue about Rest APIs.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a list of files

```
# Get list of all files and folders in library
files = s.get("{}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{}')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef"
          .format(site, library)).json()["d"]["results"]
```

for the complete solution, check this:

https://github.com/JonathanHolvey/sharepy/issues/5